# At what point does muscle mass overcome muscle strength to affect speed?

Tags: human-biology

I'm trying to think in terms of "how fast" someone can do something, like swing a bat or push a crate. Someone might have a lot of muscle mass, but that also increases how much mass an arm has to move which also increases the torque. Is there anything referable in biology that has found at least some estimate of where these two factors trade off?